VS Webview2 NewWindowRequest Handle Headers
What I am Doing: I am Developing a Own Browser Which Opens a New Tab in a Tab Format. Using Webview2 and WPF Form.
What Working Fine:
1.When a Link Targeting New/SELF Tab With Get Method Working Fine.
2.When a Link Trageting Self Tab With POST Method Working Fine.
What Not Working:
1.When a Link Trageting New Tab With POST Method Open New Tab But POST Data Not Received.
What I Have Coded:
private async void WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     LogMsg("WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted");
     if (!e.IsSuccess)
         LogMsg($"{e.InitializationException}");
     
     if (sender != null)
     {
         WebView2 wv = (WebView2)sender;
         await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
         wv.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
         wv.WebMessageReceived += WebViewControl_WebMessageReceived;
         wv.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsWebMessageEnabled = true;
         wv.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreHostObjectsAllowed = true;
                  
         CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
         options.AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled = true;
         options.ExclusiveUserDataFolderAccess = true;

     }
 }

private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
   AddTab(e.Uri);
}

private void AddTab(string url, string? headerText = null, string? userDataFolder = null)
{
    AddTab(new Uri(url), headerText, userDataFolder);
}
private void AddTab(Uri uri, string? headerText = null, string? userDataFolder = null)
{
    //increment
    _tabCount++;

    if (headerText == null)
        headerText = $"Tab {_tabCount}";

    //if userDataFolder hasn't been specified, create a folder in the user's temp folder
    //each WebView2 instance will have it's own folder
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userDataFolder))
    //userDataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + _tabCount);
    //create new instance setting userDataFolder
    WebView2 wv = new WebView2() { CreationProperties = new CoreWebView2CreationProperties() { UserDataFolder = userDataFolder } };
    wv.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
    wv.WebMessageReceived += WebViewControl_WebMessageReceived;
    CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
    options.AreBrowserExtensionsEnabled = true;
    options.ExclusiveUserDataFolderAccess = true;
    options.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount = true;
    
    //create TextBlock
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();

    //add new Run to TextBlock
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(headerText));

    //add new Run to TextBlock
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("   "));

    //create Run
    Run runHyperlink = new Run("X");
    runHyperlink.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Monotype Corsiva");
    runHyperlink.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    runHyperlink.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    //add Run to HyperLink
    Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(runHyperlink) { Name = $"hyperlink_{_tabCount}" };
    hyperlink.Click += Hyperlink_Click;

    //add Hyperlink to TextBlock
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);

    //create new instance and set Content
    HeaderedContentControl hcc = new HeaderedContentControl() { Content = textBlock };

    //add TabItem
    _webView2Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = hcc, Content = wv, Name = $"tab_{_tabCount}" });


    //navigate
    wv.Source = uri;
                
    //set selected index
    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = _webView2Tabs.Count - 1;
}

Any Solutions Will be Thankfull.
